# SNMPGET(SNMPWALK) get the wrong data type HEX-STRING

Tags: snmp

In mib file, I define one property as DisplayString. And in my test case, I set the value of this property is null. So I think the output is "", not HEX-STRING: 01. At the same time, the same column of other rows are "". Who could help me, Thank you in advance.

For example:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.3.51.3.1.14.7.1.4.1 = ""
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.3.51.3.1.14.7.1.4.2 = Hex-STRING: 01 
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.3.51.3.1.14.7.1.4.3 = ""
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.3.51.3.1.14.7.1.4.4 = Hex-STRING: 01 
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.3.51.3.1.14.7.1.4.5 = ""
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.3.51.3.1.14.7.1.4.6 = Hex-STRING: 01
```

All the values of this column I set are null.

Comment: First put your MIB documents to the proper folder so that your SNMP utilities can load them. Then you might see a better display instead of the one you pasted. Second, if any value is not as you wished, go down to packet level.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is hex-string of '01' and you were trying to return a zero-length string (""), then you're not setting the return length correctly.  You need to set both the data properly (in this case, the data can be a pointer to a string containing nothing) and the length, which needs to be set to 0.  It appears for some of the data in your question, you're setting the data length to 1.

Remember that SNMP is designed to pass any type of byte stream, including those with a '0' byte in the middle (or more).  So you can't use a NULL-terminated string and must return the true length of the string because you may want to actually return 0x65 0x00 0x65, which isn't possible with a NULL terminated string unless you can set the length to 3.